# Slider always a fixed height - and can't remove height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm currently working on a project, but I'm having some troubles making the slider adapt, it resizes the images, but the outer slider, and masks, must have a fixed width - otherwise they don't show up at all?

I have tried replacing the height with auto, I've tried adding a min and max height but in doing this, none of the images show up but the outer mask does...

I'm very confused, I'm thinking it must be something to do with the jQuery file I pulled from online. As I don't know all that much about JavaScript / jQuery.

Could anyone please point me into the right direction?

```
// TABBED SLIDER

var homeSlider = {
    vars: {
        pos: 0,
        locked: 0,
        duration: 1000
    },
    helpers: {
        getPercent: function (str) {
            var foo = str.substring(str.indexOf('left:') + 5);
            return parseInt(foo.substring(0, foo.indexOf('%')));
        },
        unlock: function () {
            homeSlider.vars.locked = 0;
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        $('.slider .mask').on('mouseenter mouseleave', homeSlider.peek.over);
        $('.slider .mask').on('click', homeSlider.nav.arrow);
        $('.slider-nav a').on('click', homeSlider.nav.menu);
    },
    peek: {
        over: function (e) {
            if (e.type == 'mouseenter' && $(this).hasClass('left')) {
                homeSlider.peek.move(0);
            } else if (e.type == 'mouseenter' && $(this).hasClass('right')) {
                homeSlider.peek.move(0);
            } else {
                homeSlider.peek.move(0);
            }
        },
        move: function (dist) {
            $('.slider-wrap .outer').stop().animate({ 'left': dist }, 300);
        }
    },
    nav: {
        arrow: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (homeSlider.vars.locked === 0) {
                homeSlider.vars.locked = 1;
                if ($(this).hasClass('left')) {
                    homeSlider.move.direction(0);
                } else {
                    homeSlider.move.direction(1);
                }
            }
        },
        menu: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (homeSlider.vars.locked === 0) {
                homeSlider.vars.locked = 1;
                homeSlider.move.toSlide($(e.target.hash));
            }
        },
        update: function () {
            homeSlider.move.currentClass($('.slider-nav').find('a[href="#' + $('.slider .current').attr('id') + '"]').parent());
            var offset = $('.slider-nav li.current').position().left / $('.slider-nav').width() * 100;
            $('.slider-nav .highlight').stop().animate({ 'left': offset + '%' }, homeSlider.vars.duration, 'easeInOutQuart');
            $('.arrow.right span').text($('.slider-nav').find('a[href="#' + $('.slider .current').next().attr('id') + '"]').text());
            $('.arrow.left span').text($('.slider-nav').find('a[href="#' + $('.slider .current').prev().attr('id') + '"]').text());
        }
    },
    move: {
        direction: function (dir) {
            var $curr = $('.slider .current');
            if (dir === 1) {
                homeSlider.vars.pos -= 100;
                if ($curr.next().is(':last-child')) {
                    homeSlider.move.firstToLast();
                    homeSlider.move.animate(homeSlider.vars.pos, true);
                } else {
                    homeSlider.move.animate(homeSlider.vars.pos, false);
                }
                homeSlider.move.currentClass($curr.next());
            } else {
                homeSlider.vars.pos += 100;
                if ($curr.prev().is(':first-child')) {
                    homeSlider.move.lastToFirst();
                    homeSlider.move.animate(homeSlider.vars.pos, true);
                } else {
                    homeSlider.move.animate(homeSlider.vars.pos, false);
                }
                homeSlider.move.currentClass($curr.prev());
            }
            homeSlider.peek.move(0);
            homeSlider.nav.update();
        },
        toSlide: function ($elm) {
            var pos = homeSlider.helpers.getPercent($elm.attr('style')) * -1;
            if ($elm.is(':first-child')) {
                homeSlider.move.lastToFirst();
                homeSlider.move.currentClass($elm);
                homeSlider.move.animate(pos, true);
            } else if ($elm.is(':last-child')) {
                homeSlider.move.firstToLast();
                homeSlider.move.currentClass($elm);
                homeSlider.move.animate(pos, true);
            } else {
                homeSlider.move.currentClass($elm);
                homeSlider.move.animate(pos, false);
            }
            homeSlider.nav.update();
            homeSlider.vars.pos = pos;
        },
        currentClass: function ($elm) {
            $elm.addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
        },
        animate: function (pos, flush) {
            $('.slider .tray').animate({ 'left': pos + '%' }, homeSlider.vars.duration, 'easeInOutQuart', function () {
                if (flush) {
                    homeSlider.move.flush();
                } else {
                    homeSlider.helpers.unlock();
                }
            });
        },
        firstToLast: function () {
            var $elm = $('.slider section:first-child');
            pos = homeSlider.helpers.getPercent($('.slider section:last-child').attr('style')) + 100;
            $clone = $elm.clone();
            $elm.addClass('remove');
            $clone.removeAttr('style').css({ 'left': pos + '%' }).appendTo($('.slider .tray'));
        },
        lastToFirst: function () {
            var $elm = $('.slider section:last-child');
            pos = homeSlider.helpers.getPercent($('.slider section:first-child').attr('style')) - 100;
            $clone = $elm.clone();
            $elm.addClass('remove');
            $clone.removeAttr('style').css({ 'left': pos + '%' }).prependTo($('.slider .tray'));
        },
        flush: function () {
            $('.slider .tray section.remove').remove();
            homeSlider.helpers.unlock();
        }
    }
};
var helper = {
    init: function () {
        helper.center();
        $(window).resize(helper.center);
    },
    center: function () {
        $.each($('.slider section img'), function (i, elm) {
            $(elm).css({
                marginTop: -$(elm).height() / 2,
                top: '50%',
                position: 'relative'
            });
        });
    }
};
homeSlider.init();
// helper.init();

// END OF TABBED SLIDER ------
```

and here's the little bit of CSS -

```
.slider-wrap .slider {
    margin-top: 80px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

I've tried changing the height to;

auto - didn't work, completely removed everything
100% - did the exact same as auto
min and max height - showed the outer frameworks of the slider, but images didn't show up?

Any suggestions would greatly help... thank you.

EDIT: here's a link to the test site - http://stuartgreen.me.uk/events-test/

Comment: It would really help if you could post a link to somewhere where we can test out what you mean - it's very hard to tell just from reading the code! If you can't link directly to where you are playing around, try creating a  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) so that people can play around with the issue.

Comment: Certainly, sorry I'll upload it to a test file on my FTP now and edit the post, thank you!

Comment: Your image container has position: absolute so your slider can't resize itself based on the image size.

Comment: Thanks for your post Wawy. But the removal of the absolute would mean I can't have the layout as is at the moment, correct?

Comment: most likely not, you could try getting the image size via jQuery and add it to the slider when the move function is called.

Comment: Few notes when I pushed your code through JSHint: Line 12, no radix, suggested `return parseInt(foo.substring(0, foo.indexOf('%')), 10);`. 8 undefined variables on lines: `pos` on 120, 123, 127, 130 `$clone` on 121, 123, 128, 130. Don't think they will fix your issue yet worth fixing. use `var` before them.